# Issues with background shifting and moving with page size changes

Tags: html, css

I'm having issues with keep my backgrounds intact when the page size increases or decreases (zoom in or out)

When I zoom out of my pages, the left side starts to shift veristically, but when I zoom into my page, the right sides background shifts up so you start seeing white instead of the full red its supposed  to be.

Zoomed in:
[image]

Zoomed Out:
[image]

I've tried updating the CSS of both the ride side and left side but cannot get the proper formatting.

CSS:

```
   <style>
      body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 1.1em;
      line-height: 1.5;
      }

      .container2 {
      min-height: 100vh;
      }

  /* "Retrieved from stackoverflow to fix a spill issue with our page: " */
      html, body{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
      }
.forms-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 'left-side right-side';
}

.left-side{
    padding: 9rem;
    max-width: 900px;
    background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/5088017/pexels-photo-5088017.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}

form {
    height: 550px;
    width: 80%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    /* box-shadow: 0 0 40px rgba(8, 7, 16, 0.6); */
    padding: 50px 35px;
    }
    form * {
    font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    }
    form h3 {
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 42px;
    text-align: center;
    }

    label {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    }
    input {
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.07);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    }
    ::placeholder {
    color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
    }
    button {
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #080710;
    padding: 15px 0;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 600;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

    form{
        background: #BC3838;
    }

  .right-side{
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #BC3838 0%, #BC3838 100%);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .content {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 9rem;
    margin-top: 10%;

  }
  @media (max-width: 1173px) {
    form {
  height: 460px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #BC3838;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px rgba(8, 7, 16, 0.6);
  padding: 50px 35px;
}

  .forms-container {
    background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/5239564/pexels-photo-5239564.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1);
  }
  .right-side {
    background: none;
  }
  .content{
    display: none;
  }
}

    footer{
        padding: 5vw;
        background-color: black;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: flex-start;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        margin-top: 0px;
      }
      footer .footer-elements{
        padding-bottom: 40px;
      }
      footer h9{
        color: white;
        font-weight: 600;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
      }
      footer li{
        list-style: none;
        color: grey;
        padding: 10px 0;
        font-size: 15px;
        cursor:pointer
      }

   </style>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
        <div class="container2">
         <div class="forms-container">
                <div class="left-side">
                  <form method="post" action="register.php">
                    <div class="input-container">
                      <h3>Register</h3>
                      <label for="fullname">Full Name</label>
                      <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" id="fullname">
                      <label for="email">Email</label>
                      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" id="email">
                      <label for="phone_number">Phone Number</label>
                      <input type="phone-number" name="phone_number" placeholder="Phone">
                      <label for="password">Password</label>
                      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required> 
                      <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Register</button>
                    </div>
                  </form>
               </div>
               <div class="right-side">
                 <div class="content">
                        <h1 class="register-header">Login</h1>
                        <p class="register-text">Already have an account? Login here!</p>
                        <a href="../Register Page/Login Page V3.html"><button>Login to your account</button></a>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
    <section class="footer">
        <footer>
          <div class="footer-elements">
            <h9>Our Products</h9>
            <li>Math</li>
            <li>Enligh</li>
            <li>Coding</li>
            <li>Knitting</li>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h9>Customer Support</h9>
            <li>We provide support from 9:00 a.m. to midnight EST, seven days a week.</li>
            <h9>Phone</h9>
            <li>1-800-800-8000</li>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h9>Acces a course</h9>
            <li>Click here to login!</li>
            <li>Click here to register!</li>
            <li>Forgot your password?</li>
          </div>
        </footer>
      </section>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Zoomed in work fine for me, delete `max-width:900px;` in `.left-side` should work when zoomed out.

Comment: Thank you, looks like the zoom out was fixed by removing that but the zoom in is still happening. Usually after 100% you'll start seeing the right sides background rising. @Shuo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This :

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.container2 {
    min-height: 100vh;
}

/* "Retrieved from stackoverflow to fix a spill issue with our page: " */
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.forms-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 'left-side right-side';
}

.left-side {
    padding: 9rem;
    max-width: 900px;
    background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/5088017/pexels-photo-5088017.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
}

form {
    height: 550px;
    width: 80%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    /* box-shadow: 0 0 40px rgba(8, 7, 16, 0.6); */
    padding: 50px 35px;
}

form * {
    font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}

form h3 {
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 42px;
    text-align: center;
}

label {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

input {
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.07);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

::placeholder {
    color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

button {
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #080710;
    padding: 15px 0;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 600;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

form {
    background: #BC3838;
}

.right-side {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #BC3838 0%, #BC3838 100%);
    opacity: 1;
}

.content {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 9rem;
    margin-top: 10%;

}

@media (max-width: 1173px) {
    form {
        height: 460px;
        width: 400px;
        background-color: #BC3838;
        position: absolute;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
        box-shadow: 0 0 40px rgba(8, 7, 16, 0.6);
        padding: 50px 35px;
    }

    .forms-container {
        background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/5239564/pexels-photo-5239564.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1);
    }

    .right-side {
        background: none;
    }

    .content {
        display: none;
    }
}

footer {
    padding: 5vw;
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

footer .footer-elements {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

footer h9 {
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

footer li {
    list-style: none;
    color: grey;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="practice.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;700;800&family=Oswald:wght@200;300;400&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0b27183842.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/harvesthq/chosen/gh-pages/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/harvesthq/chosen/gh-pages/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container2">
        <div class="forms-container">
            <div class="left-side">
                <form method="post" action="register.php">
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <h3>Register</h3>
                        <label for="fullname">Full Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" id="fullname">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" id="email">
                        <label for="phone_number">Phone Number</label>
                        <input type="phone-number" name="phone_number" placeholder="Phone">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Register</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="right-side">
                <div class="content">
                    <h1 class="register-header">Login</h1>
                    <p class="register-text">Already have an account? Login here!</p>
                    <a href="../Register Page/Login Page V3.html"><button>Login to your account</button></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="footer-elements">
            <h9>Our Products</h9>
            <li>Math</li>
            <li>Enligh</li>
            <li>Coding</li>
            <li>Knitting</li>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h9>Customer Support</h9>
            <li>We provide support from 9:00 a.m. to midnight EST, seven days a week.</li>
            <h9>Phone</h9>
            <li>1-800-800-8000</li>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h9>Acces a course</h9>
            <li>Click here to login!</li>
            <li>Click here to register!</li>
            <li>Forgot your password?</li>
        </div>
    </footer>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ,I did try that in the past and the problem I get is that the footer now starts moving when I zoom out, it doesn't stay at the bottom. This is when I change the height from vh to a percentage. @Prince